# cannot install "[pycharm-professional": snap not found

Tags: ubuntu, pycharm, ubuntu-16.04

I would like to install Pycharm community edition on my Ubuntu so I ran this command

```
sudo snap install [pycharm-professional|pycharm-community] --classic
```

but it threw me the following error:

```
cannot install "[pycharm-professional": snap not found
```

I am pretty sure snap is installed.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You're supposed to choose which one you want to install, not just blindly copy the command. `sudo snap install pycharm-community --classic`.

Comment: Ohh thanks, it should have been obvious

Comment: But then i get the following error error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Mount snap "pycharm-community" (202) (info failed to parse: invalid confinement type: "classic")

Answer (score 1):

Well as @tkausl pointed out, you have to choose between the 2 versions:

- Either install the professional edition (requires a licence):

```
sudo snap install pycharm-professional --classic
```

- or install the community edition:

```
sudo snap install pycharm-community --classic
```